# C, Bash - processes that run bash scripts and work in parallel on the same file

Tags: c, bash, unix, process, fork

This is what I need:
I made a C program, it forks 2 childs: P1, P2
I also made some bash scripts.

I need P1 to run script1.sh, and P2 to run script2.sh.
At the moment I'm using the function `system("script_name.sh")` or `system("script_name &")` to make it asynchronous, I don't know if it's the right choice because for now they don't work as I want. Btw:

script1.sh does this:

```
# it search a word in a dictionary and write in a file the exact line in which that 
# word is in the dictionary, i.e. word="a" is in position "1" so 
# it will write "1" in the first line of file.

 while read line; 
 do 
 sleep 1
     TRASFORMATA=$( echo "$line" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" | sed -e 's/ //g' )  
     echo "WORDS TO SEARCH IN DICTIONARY : $TRASFORMATA:" 
     WORD=$( fgrep -w -i "$TRASFORMATA" "$dictfile" )  # got from dictionary
     echo $WORD 
  if [ -z "$WORD" ]  ## if it's not in dictionary
  then
     echo "$WORD not found!" 
     echo 
  else              
     echo "Word and relative line found.........."
##### if found, it write the relative line to a file #####
     LINE1=$( fgrep -w -n "$WORD" "$dictfile" | sed s/:$WORD//g )   
     echo "$LINE1" >> "$FILE_OUTPUT"       
  fi
 done < "$FILE_INPUT"
```

script2.sh does this:

```
# delete lines starting with letter 'z' FROM SAME FILE THAT USES script1.sh
sleep 1
while true;
do
sleep 2
echo "DELETING WORDS "
sed -i '/^z/d' "$FILE_OUTPUT"
done
```

**They work on the SAME file (.txt).** 
What I want is to run them **at the same moment** and they have to work by turns, I mean that after P! has read the first line with its script1, P2 has to run its script2, same with second line, third line, etc...

How can I do this from C program? The important thing is that every process runs one script, and these scripts has to be executed in parallel alternating them.
**In this way I reach my aim that is to let 2 processes to produce one output together in order to allowa one third process to read that output and work on it!**

I hope it's clear

Thanks for your help

Comment: your explanation isn't clear because 1) running scripts as "script &" "script2 &" will run them "asynchronous".  You hint at the end of your explanation they are in fact intended to be "synchronized" 2) the file has no letter z lines written by script1 so how can script2 delete them 3) why didn't you write the whole thing in python, perl etc etc something better?????

Comment: well they don't have to be "synchronous" because if I use system("script1") script2 has to wait for script1 to finish and that's not what I want, and I didn't wrote the content of file they use because it's part of my c program and i contains word with 'z' .
I choose C because I'm studying it and I wanted to try this thing

Answer (score 1):

Interleaving the actual executions of the processes is very awkward.

To interleave the output, have each script write its STDOUT to a pipe, then write a small program which reads one line from each pipe in turn, and writes it to the output.

However, this seems like a long way round the problem. If the two processes genuinely need to be synchronised - each executes exactly one processing step in turn - the simplest approach is to have a single process which executes the commands sequentially. Concurrency is hard - don't use it if you don't need it.

Comment: I'm studying C language and SO, so concurrency, the problem is that I have to study it by my self so I succeeded in making a c program that does what I want, the problem is that my solution was making them synchronous with system function and it used to work but I actually need concurrency. Btw thanks

Comment: @Frank So is the only thing that has to happen 'at the same time' the output? In that case, writing to a pipe and then interleaving externally is probably what you want to do.

Comment: yes, they have to create the output 'at the same time' some per process. I heard about pipe, but I have no idea about that. If you could give me an example related to my problem I'll be grateful for that? thanks